# validation is not working if text field and button are not in the same form tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I had a text field and button inside a form tag.If i dont enter the data in form the validation should work and give a popup ,which is working fine.

But if I have the button outside of the form ,the validation is not working.can some help me how to fix this.

```
JSfiddel:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h5q8q5mu/15/

Thanks

Comment: The warning message that you shouldn't link to JS Fiddle without putting code in the question doesn't mean you should mark a random bit of text as code.

Comment: Your live demo doesn't demonstrate the problem you described anyway. It just throws the error `angular is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

No need of having a button for a validation, it will automatically validate if there is no input:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="txt" required>
  </form>
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  <p>The input's valid state is:</p>
  <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/h5q8q5mu/19/)**